# how to do inner join with composite key

Tags: mysql, join, composite-primary-key

> I have `card_type` table in which there is `card_id` is
>   `auto_increment` key and `cardtpe` is `primary key`. The another table
>   which I have is `activities` table. The `columns` in activities table
>   are `activity_id` with `auto_increment` key and `activity` column with
>   `primary key`.  The third table is `actual_alldetails` table. The
>   columns in `actual_alldetails` are `id` with `auto_increment` key and
>   `(emp_code,activity_id,card_id)` column with `composite key`. The
>   fourth table is `employee` table and columns in these table are
>   `emp_code` with `primary key` and `emp_name`.

When I am trying to execute one of my query:-

```
SELECT i.*,
       d.Date,
       a.in_time,
       a.out_time,
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.out_time))-(TIME_TO_SEC(a.in_time))) AS duration,
       c.cardtype,
       a.wo,
       v.activity,
       a.quty,
       a.wastage,
       a.mcusage,
       a.actual_wastage
FROM employee_details i
INNER JOIN actual_alldetails a ON i.emp_code=a.emp_code
INNER JOIN attendance_date d ON d.date_id=a.date_id
INNER JOIN card_type c ON c.card_id=a.card_id
INNER JOIN activities v ON v.activity_id=a.activity_id
WHERE d.Date='2016-01-30'
ORDER BY v.activity;
```

It show me error like:

> Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP
>   columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause.

I don't get understand why it show me error like these. Is it because I am doing inner join with one primary key and one composite key??
If my prediction is right then what is the correct query to do these??
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it:

> Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause.

you have a select statement which contains an aggregated value `SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.out_time)` and a non aggregated value `TIME_TO_SEC(a.in_time)`

I don't know what exactly the result is you are hoping for but you either have to apply an aggregating function to the second value or you have do add a group by as the error message says so it knows what to group on.

For example change the query to this:

```
SELECT i.*,
   d.Date,
   a.in_time,
   a.out_time,
   SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.out_time))-(TIME_TO_SEC(a.in_time))) AS duration,
   c.cardtype,
   a.wo,
   v.activity,
   a.quty,
   a.wastage,
   a.mcusage,
   a.actual_wastage
FROM employee_details i
INNER JOIN actual_alldetails a ON i.emp_code=a.emp_code
INNER JOIN attendance_date d ON d.date_id=a.date_id
INNER JOIN card_type c ON c.card_id=a.card_id
INNER JOIN activities v ON v.activity_id=a.activity_id
WHERE d.Date='2016-01-30'
GROUP BY i.emp_code
ORDER BY v.activity;
```

I'm guessing at the id value of your employees: `i.emp_code`

Answer (score 0):

Look closer at this line:

> `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.out_time))-(TIME_TO_SEC(a.in_time))) AS duration,`

There is a `SUM()` function here that looks *very* odd and most likely triggers your error message. Try to remove the `SUM`.